# TypeError: TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object. While i am trying to create django object

Tags: django, django-models

I am faced with issue while trying to create object from django models. I have the **Fixture** model

```
from django.db import models                               
from django.contrib.postgres.fields 
import JSONField       
import datetime                                            
from django.utils import timezone

class Fixture(models.Model):
   fixture = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
   league_id = models.ForeignKey('League',null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, to_field="league")                       
   event_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)               
   event_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(null=True)          
   firstHalfStart = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
   secondHalfStart = models.DateTimeField(null=True)          
   round_count = models.CharField(max_length=10)
   status = models.CharField(max_length=20)                      
   statusShort = models.CharField(max_length=15)              
   elapsed = models.IntegerField(null=True)                   
   venue = models.CharField(max_length=170)
   referee = models.CharField(max_length=70)                  
   home_team_id = models.IntegerField(null=True)              
   away_team_id = models.IntegerField(null=True)              
   goal_of_home_team = models.IntegerField(null=True)         
   goal_of_away_team = models.IntegerField(null=True)         
   half_time_score = models.CharField(max_length=15)          
   full_time_score = models.CharField(max_length=15)
   extratime = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   penalty = models.CharField(max_length=50)                  
   lastModified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

I have json file where i store some json data from which i want to create objects of this model

```
fixtures_date = open(os.path.abspath("/data/data/com.termux/files/home/storage/forecast/endpoints/leagues_date.txt"), "r")                                                                                                                  
leagues_json = json.load(fixtures_date)                    
leagues_json = leagues_json["api"]["fixtures"]             
for item in leagues_json:
   fixture_id = item["fixture_id"]                            
   league_id = item["league_id"]
   event_date = item["event_date"]                            
   event_timestamp = item["event_timestamp"]                  
   firstHalfStart = item["firstHalfStart"]                    
   secondHalfStart = item["secondHalfStart"]                  
   round_count = item["round"]                                status = item["status"]
   statusShort = item["statusShort"]                          
   elapsed = item["elapsed"]                                  
   venue = item["venue"]                                      
   referee = item["referee"]                                  
   home_team_id = item["homeTeam"]["team_id"]                 
   away_team_id = item["awayTeam"]["team_id"]                 
   goal_of_home_team = item["goalsHomeTeam"]                   
   goal_of_away_team = item["goalsAwayTeam"]                  
   half_time_score = item["score"]["halftime"]                
   full_time_score = item["score"]["fulltime"]                
   extratime = item["score"]["extratime"]                        
   penalty = item["score"]["penalty"]
```

Now i am trying to create objects from this variables

```
fixt = Fixture.objects.create(fixture = fixture_id,
league_id_id = league_id,
event_date = event_date,
event_timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(event_timestamp),
firstHalfStart = firstHalfStart,
secondHalfStart = secondHalfStart,   
round_count = round_count,status =status,
statusShort = statusShort,
elapsed = elapsed,
venue = venue,referee= referee,
home_team_id = home_team_id,  
away_team_id = away_team_id,  
goal_of_home_team = goal_of_home_team,
goal_of_away_team = goal_of_away_team, 
half_time_score = half_time_score,
full_time_score = full_time_score,
extratime = extratime,
penalty = penalty,
lastModified = timezone.now())
```

While i am running this script. I am getting this error here is full Traceback

```
>>> import fixture
/data/data/com.termux/files/home/storage/predictions/forecast
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/storage/predictions/forecast/fixture.py", line 53, in <module>
fixt = Fixture.objects.create(fixture = fixture_id,league_id_id = league_id,event_date = event_date,event_timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(event_timestamp),firstHalfStart = firstHalfStart,secondHalfStart = secondHalfStart, round_count = round_count,status =status,statusShort = statusShort,elapsed = elapsed,venue = venue,referee= referee,home_team_id = home_team_id, away_team_id = away_team_id, goal_of_home_team = goal_of_home_team,goal_of_away_team = goal_of_away_team, half_time_score = half_time_score,full_time_score = full_time_score,extratime = extratime,penalty = penalty,lastModified = timezone.now())
File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/storage/predictions/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
 File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/storage/predictions/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 422, in create
 obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
 File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/storage/predictions/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 741, in save
 force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/storage/predictions/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 779, in save_base
force_update, using, update_fields,
File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/storage/predictions/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 870, in _save_table
 result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
 File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/storage/predictions/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 908, in _do_insert
using=using, raw=raw)
 File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/storage/predictions/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
 File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/storage/predictions/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1186, in _insert
return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
 File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/storage/predictions/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1334, in execute_sql
for sql, params in self.as_sql():
 File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/storage/predictions/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1278, in as_sql
for obj in self.query.objs
 File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/storage/predictions/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1278, in <listcomp>
for obj in self.query.objs
File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/storage/predictions/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1277, in <listcomp>
[self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]
File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/storage/predictions/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1218, in prepare_value
value = field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=self.connection)
 File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/storage/predictions/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 789, in get_db_prep_save
return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/storage/predictions/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1429, in get_db_prep_value
   File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/storage/predictions/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1408, in get_prep_value
value = super().get_prep_value(value)
 File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/storage/predictions/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1268, in get_prep_value
return self.to_python(value)
 File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/storage/predictions/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1369, in to_python
parsed = parse_datetime(value)
 File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/storage/predictions/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/dateparse.py", line 106, in parse_datetime
  match = datetime_re.match(value)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

From this traceback i didnt understand what i am doing wrong. Can anyone guide me

**UPD**
My Fixture model have four potential datetime fields and json value for each of these fields have the following data type

```
event_timestamp = <class 'int'>
event_date = <class 'str'>
```

But **firstHalfStart** and **secondHalfStart** sometimes contain "integer" values and sometimes "NoneType" values

Answer (score 0):

Django’s `DateTimeField` generally works with Python `datetime` and `date` objects, it can however automatically parse strings into `datetime` or `date` objects.

Somewhere the `json` data you are trying to insert into a `datetime` field on your model is not of correct type. Django tries to parse it automatically for you but fails.

Make sure all `datetime` fields are valid `datetime` strings or timestamps are correctly parsed before passing to `model` `create` method

Comment: Suggest me how i can check them.

Comment: You need to debug the values in `leagues_json `. Print the date values to your console and check the type of those values `print(item["firstHalfStart"]) type(item["firstHalfStart"])`.

Comment: Post the json response you get from the `fixtures` in your `question`

Comment: Updated my question with neccessary data

Comment: I can not help you if I can't see the `data`. Please provide the `data` you are trying to process.